# Fastapi Basic Auth popup is not Opening when Security Implementation is in the router File

Tags: python, fastapi

```
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security import HTTPBasic, HTTPBasicCredentials

import secrets

from fastapi.security import HTTPBasic, HTTPBasicCredentials

security = HTTPBasic()
app = APIRouter(prefix="")

def get_current_username(credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(security)):
    correct_username = secrets.compare_digest(credentials.username, "user")
    correct_password = secrets.compare_digest(credentials.password, "password")
    if not (correct_username and correct_password):
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect email or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Basic"},
        )
    return credentials.username


@app.get("/users")
async def get_all_users(username: str = Depends(get_current_username)):
return username
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24AK9.png)

I am trying to implement http basic auth module of fastapi inside of my router file where I have extended Fastapi Router Module. when I am directly accessing the URL at that time pop is not opening and getting not authenticated message

Comment: Please properly indent the codes. Hope this may helps https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/http-basic-auth/